# Example of an open map on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is not a submersion

Tags: real-analysis

I am searching for an example of a map $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ that is open but is not a submersion... I know that any constant map is not a submersion, but it is indeed closed, I am wondering for an example where $f$ is an open map.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: It depends on your choice of topology.

Comment: @FlybyNight: as far as I know a "submersion" is only defined for manifolds; hence you need the standard topologies on $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @FlybyNight, to me, a submersion is a map whose derivative is surjective.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip So, differentiability only makes sense with respect to the "standard topologies"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the map $(x,y) \to x^3.\,\,$

Comment: this is a good one! I do appreciate.